# Why do I get a "SSL error: called a function you should not call" with Django

Tags: python, django, apache, postgresql, ssl

I have a `Python 3.5`/`Django 1.10` app served by `Apache`/`mod_wsgi` over SSL. It is connected to a `Postgres 9.5.2` database (with `psycopg2==2.6.2`)  and is running on a server at `AlwaysData`

It works fine most of time but I have sometimes an error that I don't understand.

```
(SSL error: called a function you should not call)
```

If I put the following database settings : The error seems to happen every time

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'host',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sslmode': 'require',
        },
    }
}
```

It seems to occur while querying the database.

```
# django/db/backends/utils.py line 64
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

The problem occurs when REST api (made using django-rest-framework) is called by a Angular2 app.

I have activated the following settings:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Why does it happen? How to fix this problem in my Django project.

Note : [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19286131/117092) looks similar but I don't manage the OpenSSL layer directly so it is  not very helpful.

EDIT : here is the full traceback

```
File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  474.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  434.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  471.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "proj/apps/costs/apis.py" in get
  296.         data = self.get_spends_stats(cost_items, perimeter, start_date, end_date)

File "proj/apps/costs/apis.py" in get_spends_stats
  306.         for building in buildings:

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  256.         self._fetch_all()

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1087.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql()

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  835.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /costs/api/benchmark/cost-center/3/38/2016-01/2017-12/
Exception Value: SSL error: called a function you should not call
```

Comment: It may help : I am using psycopg2==2.6.2 for Postgres

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace after `utils.py:64`? Maybe something may give a hint about what is going on in inner layers...

Comment: I've added the traceback . Unfortunately it doesn't go deeper than `utils.py:64`

Comment: The 'sslmode': 'require' option seems to cause the error every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be solved by changing the database settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'host',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sslmode': 'disable',
        },
    }
}
```

If not set the option is using `prefer` as default (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-ssl.html) which seems to have unpredicted behavior.

I guess that the root cause is an OpenSSL mismatch between Apache and Postgres. It has to be investigated.

The current fix makes the database connection not secured but this is another story.

Comment: Did you mismatched versions due to try my answer? I'm sorry. I hope it could been easily reverted. There should not be a mismatch possible if all packages are installed by your OS distribution system and you installed only updates.

The letter "g" at the end of libssl "1.0.2g" is not important for dynamic loader and you can replace it successfully by recompiling the lib SSL on a machine with an identical OS.

Comment: Any different version number would probably require to recompile the app due to different header files and it can be too much work. The most complicated is to recompile all necessary Apache mod_* on a identical system. Even that it is strange and you want to recompile at most only one, it is easier by my experience a few years ago, than to try to "simply" copy something new small from elsewhere different distribution.

Comment: The traditional "mod_wsgi" (not the "express" mod_wsgi) is a Python wrapped to a Apache module. All Apache extensions (mod_*) should be recompiled together, otherwise you can not use the automated scripts for rebuild.
(added a new paragraph to my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a `psycopg2` bug (or rather, [as piro pointed out](/questions/40278044/why-do-i-get-a-ssl-error-called-a-function-you-should-not-call-with-django/40402498?noredirect=1#comment68058988_40402498), the underlying `libpq`'s bug). It appears to be violating the required call order - [likely not waiting for some event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286131/why-does-openssl-give-me-a-called-a-function-you-should-not-call-error). Since this occurs irregularly, it can be a race condition.

It even provides incomplete information about the error which is another bug. It should use [`ERR_print_errors()`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:ERR_print_errors%283%29) to get the full message which has the format `[pid]:error:[error code]:[library name]:[function name]:[reason string]:[file name]:[line]:[optional text message]`.

Comment: psycopg uses libpq for ssl communication. It seems a libpq bug to me.

Comment: @piro well, the specific piece of code responsible is a secondary matter here. This doesn't undermine the helpfulness of your tip, of course.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Of course: I'm just addressing the investigation to where I think the error lies. libpq and psycopg are different projects, maintained by different people. Even the "print" hint could be useful... but to the right people. psycopg doesn't call openssh function directly so if some code can be improved it should be libpq

Answer (score 1):

There was a related [bug #58956 in Apache + OpenSSL](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58956) in SSL_shutdown handshake, ending with exactly the same error message, that has been [fixed by OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/64193c821854) in February 2016. Try to upgrade to 1.0.2g or 1.1.0 or newer.

---

**EDIT:** If you have some 1.0.2 version (maybe more versions, but your package of interest is linked to 1.0.2) then the upgrade of SSL is worth considering. The version 1.1.0 is here written only for completeness to anybody can easily check a version later, whether is related to this bug. Nobody have now a 1.1 probably on a production hosting and a self-made upgrade to it would be probably a bad idea.