# Using Google Cloud SQL WITHOUT Network Authorization

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, cloud, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google Cloud PostgreSQL with my django rest api developed locally and to be able to connect to the database, you are required to enter an IP address of where do you want to connect from. My team and I are using dynamic IP addresses and we should change the IP address everytime in the cloud interface in order to connect. Is there any other way? I wanted to try the SSL thing but it's too complicated. Any thoughts? 
Thanks

Edit:
I am trying to use SSL and this is what I added to my settings.py but I am getting an error:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'HOST': '00.000.00.000',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'sslmode': 'require',
        'ssl': {
            'ca': 'certs/server-ca.pem',
            'cert': 'certs/client-cert.pem',
            'key': 'certs/client-key.pem'
            }
    },
}
```

}

The ssl files are located in a folder called certs and this folder is in the same directory as the settings.py file.

This is the error I get when running the server:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "ssl"
```

Comment: One option could be to use https://www.noip.com/ who provide a service to establish a "fixed" IP? If you can't get a static IP from your ISP.

Comment: We are using many and different laptops for the dev, I don't wanna do this everytime.

Comment: Then yes I would say your best option is to implement ssl https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ssl-instance

Comment: I already read this article, I have a problem with Django and how to set it up, not google cloud.

Comment: might be a version of python, openssl or django problem... have a look here as seems some bugs: https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/issues/2755 and also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278044/why-do-i-get-a-ssl-error-called-a-function-you-should-not-call-with-django

Comment: Have you tried using a CIDR range notation instead of introducing each IP manually? your dynamic IP allocation should have a definite range.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [cloud proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) This will enable the use of an authenticated connection, however you will not need to worry about the IP or authentication aspect.

Using cloud proxy - allows a dedicated connection to your Cloud SQL instance (this is an authenticated connection). Once this is correctly set up, simply point your application to the proxy and all traffic will be sent to the back-end Cloud SQL instance.

For bonus points, cloud proxy can be configured dynamically using the VM metadata to setup the environment. I have used it like this previously with Terraform where it used to point to a specific cloud sql instance and it saves a lot of effort.